# Using javascript to change the value of a selectbox with an on change event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i've made a much nicer looking JSfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/pNzag/3/) That includes the expected json response, and the relevant JS.

What it's doing so far is making an ajax call for the json, and triggering an onchange which starts splitting the json up by materials, then it is putting each material group into an optgroup. which is displayed to the user.

I want to be able to set the value of the materials selection box after the first change is called so that the current usage is shown instead of the first timber one. any ideas how to fix my code to do this? it's had me stumped for a few hours now.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(

function() {

    var selectData, $states, firstRun, herp_current_material, value;
    firstRun = 0;

    function updateSelects() {
        $('#id__material').empty();
        var cities = $.map(selectData[this.value], function(city) {
            m = city.split(":");
            if (m.length == 3) {
                value = m[1] + ":" + m[2];
                value = value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
                if (document.getElementById(m[0])) {
                    $('#' + m[0]).append($("<option />").text(m[2]).attr("value", value));
                }
                else {
                    if (firstRun === 0) {
                        console.log(m[1]);
                        if (m[0] == "Current") {
                            herp_current_material = m[1];
                        }
                    }
                    $('#id__material').append($("<optgroup />").attr("label", m[0]).attr("id", m[0]));
                    $('#' + m[0]).append($("<option />").text(m[2]).attr("value", value));
                }
            }
            else if (m.length == 4) {
                value = m[1] + ":" + m[2] + ":" + m[0];
                value = value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
                if (document.getElementById(m[0])) {
                    $('#' + m[0]).append($("<option />").text(m[2]).attr("value", value));
                }
                else {
                    $('#id__material').append($("<optgroup />").attr("label", m[0]).attr("id", m[0]));
                    $('#' + m[0]).append($("<option />").text(m[2]).attr("value", value));
                }
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        });
        $("optgroup[label='Local']").insertBefore("optgroup[label='Global']");
        $("optgroup[label='Current']").insertBefore("optgroup[label='Local']");
    }

    $.getJSON("/appdata/joinery/ajax/usage/" + return_item_uuid() + "/" + return_component_code() + "/", function(data) {
        var state;
        selectData = data;
        $states = $('#materialwidgettypeselector').change(updateSelects);
        $states.change();
        if (firstRun === 0) {
            $('#materialwidgettypeselector option:text="' + herp_current_material + '"').attr('selected', 'selected');
            firstRun = 1;
        }
    });
});​
```

Html:

```
<label for="id__material">Material:</label></td><td style="font-weight:lighter; width:200px;"><select id="materialwidgettypeselector"><option value="timber">Timber</option><option value="sheet">Sheet</option><option value="door_blank">Door blank</option><option value="profiled">Profiled</option><option value="glass">Glass</option><option value="fitting">Fitting</option></select><br><select name="_material" id="id__material"><optgroup label="Local" id="Local"><option value="timber:softie">Softie</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Global" id="Global"><option value="timber:carcase">Carcase</option><option value="timber:cill">Cill</option></optgroup></select>
```

Json:

```
{"door_blank": [], "fitting": ["Frame:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "IEL:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "IEL:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "IER:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "IER:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "IL:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "IL:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "IML:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "IML:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "IMR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "IMR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "IR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "IR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "JL:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "JL:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "JML:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "JML:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "JMR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "JMR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "JR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "JR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OEL:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OEL:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OER:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OER:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OHEL:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OHEL:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OHER:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OHER:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OHL:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OHL:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OHML:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OHML:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OHMR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OHMR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OHR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OHR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OL:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OL:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OML:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OML:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OMR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OMR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "OR:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "OR:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "frame:fitting:Bifold doors:Bifold Doors", "frame:fitting:Sliding doors:Sliding Doors", "Global:fitting:Left", "Global:fitting:Right", "Global:fitting:Top"], "sheet": ["Global:sheet:Anti ballistic", "Global:sheet:Anti vandle steel sheet", "Global:sheet:Blue cladding", "Global:sheet:Core", "Global:sheet:Green cladding", "Global:sheet:Inner veneer", "Global:sheet:Insulation", "Global:sheet:Non specific layer", "Global:sheet:Outer veneer", "Local:sheet:Softie", "Current:sheet:"], "profiled": [], "timber": ["Global:timber:Carcase", "Global:timber:Cill", "Local:timber:Softie"]}​
```

Comment: After a quick glance at the jsfiddle I am getting a console error Uncaught ReferenceError: return_item_uuid is not defined I do not see that function in your example or in the fiddle. Also it seems the return_component_code() function is also missing

Comment: Ignore that, return_item_uuid is a global and for this page returns `B9109E40-2CAB-11E2-AB03-005056C00008` as is return_component_code which returns, `main:slash:left:slash:left_jamb_1` that ajax call won't work for you guys, which is why i pasted the json data in the HTML pane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set the selected option of a select list use syntax similar to:

```
$("select#myselectid").val(someobject.objectproperty).attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#form select[name=country]').val('United States');